# ODBC connector for interBase

Tags: odbc, interbase

im trying to connect to to an interBase database, and create a ASP.net application.
im using a 64bit machine but for sum reason I cant seem to add the data source from the data source administrator. im using a program called data direct which worked perfectly on my 32bit machine.

can any one suggest how I may be bale to solve this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is (as of IB XE) a 64 bit client for IB, I don't think Embarcadero/DataDirect currently ship a 64 bit ODBC driver. Therefore you would need to use a 32 bit app pool and [set up the data source using the 32 bit ODBC control panel](http://support.embarcadero.com/article/40507) (or directly in the 32 bit registry). This *will* work on a 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Craig. 
But a bit suggest:
You can step the ODBC creation, by using directly and odbc.odbcConnection:

```
$  Dim sConnStr As String 
$  sConnStr = "Driver={INTERSOLV Interbase ODBC Driver (*.gdb)};
$        uid=sysdba;
$        password=masterkey;
$        database=server:path"
$  Dim oConn As New Odbc.OdbcConnection(sConnStr)
```